# Unable to access Keycloak 18.0.2 embedded h2 db file

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to access keycloak\data\h2\keycloakdb.mv using DBeaver. I am getting Wrong username or password.Any help on this is so much appreciated

I tried

Username:sa
Password:

Username:sa
Password:sa

Username:keycloak
Password:

Username:keycloak
Password:keycloak

Answer (score 6):

If anyone comes looking. The dev mode credentials for the embedded db can be found in the DatabasePropertyMappers class.

For now it seems to be:

```
username: sa
password: password
```

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/f0988a62b8f5ca211bf4aaab4f5aa11120115451/quarkus/runtime/src/main/java/org/keycloak/quarkus/runtime/configuration/mappers/DatabasePropertyMappers.java

```java
private static Optional<String> resolveUsername(Optional<String> value, ConfigSourceInterceptorContext context) {
    if (isDevModeDatabase(context)) {
        return of("sa");
    }
    
    return Database.getDatabaseKind(value.get()).isEmpty() ? value : null;
}
    
private static Optional<String> resolvePassword(Optional<String> value, ConfigSourceInterceptorContext context) {
    if (isDevModeDatabase(context)) {
        return of("password");
    }
    
    return Database.getDatabaseKind(value.get()).isEmpty() ? value : null;
}
```

Comment: Please make the point very prominent - it might save hours:
As soon as you run a dev-* DB, keycloak *won't* use db-username and db-password properties set in keycloak.conf. DatabasePropertyMappers.java will set it to hardcoded strings depending on keycloak version you use.

Answer (score 1):

> For Quarkus Distribution

You can check the default configuration in `keycloak.conf` file. Search for keycloak.conf file in your keycloak directory. The database-related properties will look something like below.

```
db=dev-mem
db-username = sa
db-password = keycloak
```

> For Wildfly Distribution

You can check for the h2 database username and password in `standalone.xml` or `domain.xml`.

Under `datasources` subsystem look for `java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS` named data source. e.g.

````
     <datasources>
       ​<drivers>
         ​<driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
           ​<xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
         ​</driver>
       ​</drivers>
       ...
       <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
           <driver>h2</driver>
           <connection-url>jdbc:h2:${jboss.server.data.dir}/keycloak;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</connection-url>
           <security>
               <user-name>sa</user-name>
               <password>?</password>
           </security>
       </datasource>
        ...
     </datasources> ```
````

Comment: I am using Distribution powered by Quarkus version and there is no standalone folder

Comment: Are you using `dev-file` database?

Comment: For Quarkus distribution that is the default database

Comment: I am trying to access default h2 database file that is generated by the Keycloak

Comment: @Kiran Try using username `sa` and password `keycloak`

Comment: Same. I got Wrong username or password

Comment: Try setting the database username and password in `keycloak.conf` file and use that. Also if you are running it locally, try to run it in development mode

Comment: It did not work